# How do I add "Pay as little as $/month" on product view page based on the final price?

Tags: price, product-view, final-price

I would like to display what the monthly payments would be for our monthly payment option, based on the final price of the product (including configurable products).  Here is a screenshot of something I would like:

[image: Pay as little as $/month]
Essentially, I would like to be able to grab the final price and split it into monthly payments and output the text after the "product.info.price".

I tried overriding the `catalog_product_view.xml` in my theme and specify a different .phtml to use, but I was not able to grab the final price... or any price for that matter.

I also tried specifying the block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" in the `catalog_product_view.xml`, but it just repeated the product price with a lot of underlying html with no way to modify it.

So, how can I override the `catalog_product_view.xml` to grab the price, do a calculation based on it, then output custom text based on that calculation after the "product.info.price" block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `catalog_product_view.xml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and use the code below:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="monthly_payment_text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/monthly_payment.phtml" after="product.info.price" />
</referenceContainer>
```

create `monthly_payment.phtml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/monthly_payment.phtml

and use the code below:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); 
$product = $this->getProduct();
$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
$month = 12;
$monthlyPay = round(($finalPrice/$month), 2);
$monthlyPay = $priceHelper->currency($monthlyPay, true, false);
?>
<p>Pay as little as <?php echo $monthlyPay; ?>/mo for <?php echo $month; ?> Months</p>
```

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Awesome!  This worked!  Is there a way to also have it update dynamically as configurable product prices are updated based on option selections?